# Fileupload a zip containing files with special chars going bananas

Tags: php, jquery, file-upload, zip, special-characters

[[ *See the Update and the Conclusion at the end, it still bugs me for not being able to explain why* ]]

---

So, I have a weird case here:

I have a file upload form that is used to upload zip/rar archives. However, if the files inside the archive contain special characters, some are shown correctly and others aren't. There is a file containing the letter `È` which is turned into a plus-sign `+` in the uploaded and moved zipfile, but a file containing the letter `Ö` is preserved correctly.

Files in zip before upload:

```
Files.zip
    Some_file_with_È.pdf
    Some_file_with_Î.pdf
    Some_file_with_Ñ.pdf
    Some_file_with_Ö.pdf
```

Files in zip after upload & move:

```
Files.zip
    Some_file_with_+.pdf  <-- Altered
    Some_file_with_+.pdf  <-- Altered
    Some_file_with_Ñ.pdf
    Some_file_with_Ö.pdf
```

I have tried encoding the form, .php file, .js file and all headers in both UTF-8 and ISO-8859-1 / ANSI, set the `AddDefaultCharset utf-8` in the Apache config, but nothing changed..

**Form HTML:**

```
<!-- The form. Also tried accept-charset="UTF-8" -->
<form id="uploadzipform" accept-charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <input type="file" name="zipfile" id="zipfile">
</form>

<!-- The target iframe to handle fileupload -->
<iframe class="uploadframe" name="zipuploadframe" id="zipuploadframe"></iframe>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$("#uploadzipform").attr(
{
    action: "/script/fileupload.php",
    method: "POST",
    enctype: "multipart/form-data",
    target: "zipuploadframe"
});

$("#uploadzipform").submit();
$("#uploadzipform").removeAttr("action method enctype target");
```

**fileupload.php:**

```
/* Irrelevant parts omitted */

$ext = strtolower(pathinfo($_FILES["zipfile"]["name"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

// Remove special chars from projectname to make filename
$project = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_ %\[\]\.\(\)%&-]/s', '', substr(utf8_decode($_POST['p']), 0, 9));
$now = date("d-m-Y H.i.s");
$filename = "{$project}_{$now}.{$ext}";

$old = $_FILES["zipfile"]["tmp_name"];
$new = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/zipfiles/" . $filename;

move_uploaded_file($old, $new);
```

---

*How* is it possible that the files containing special characters *inside* the zip get altered?

### **EDIT1**

Forgot to mention that the server runs Windows Server 2008

---

### **EDIT2**

As requested, the code to unzip the uploaded zipfile (using 7zip commandline):

```
$file = str_replace("/", "\\", $_POST['f']); // Path to the zipfile

$path = "C:\\pathtoextract";
mkdir("$path");
$cmd = 'C:\\7-Zip\\7z.exe x "' . $file . '" -aou -o' . $path;
    // x    = extract
    // -aou = append existing files with numbers
    // -o   = path to extract to
exec($cmd);
```

---

## **UPDATE**

I've tried some things and this is what happened:

Case 1: just `Ñ` and `Ö`

```
Before upload:              After upload:
 Files.zip                   Files.zip
    Some_file_with_Ñ.pdf        Some_file_with_-.pdf  <-- Altered (minus?)
    Some_file_with_Ö.pdf        Some_file_with_+.pdf  <-- Altered
```

Case 2: normal `E` and `I` + `Ñ` and `Ö`

```
Before upload:              After upload:
 Files.zip                   Files.zip
    Some_file_with_E.pdf        Some_file_with_E.pdf  <-- Not altered
    Some_file_with_I.pdf        Some_file_with_I.pdf  <-- Not altered
    Some_file_with_Ñ.pdf        Some_file_with_-.pdf  <-- Altered (minus?)
    Some_file_with_Ö.pdf        Some_file_with_+.pdf  <-- Altered
```

Case 3: normal `I` + `È`, `Ñ` and `Ö`

```
Before upload:              After upload:
 Files.zip                   Files.zip
    Some_file_with_È.pdf        Some_file_with_+.pdf  <-- Altered
    Some_file_with_I.pdf        Some_file_with_I.pdf  <-- Not altered
    Some_file_with_Ñ.pdf        Some_file_with_-.pdf  <-- Altered (minus?)
    Some_file_with_Ö.pdf        Some_file_with_+.pdf  <-- Altered
```

Case 4: `Å`, `È`, `Ñ` and `Ö`

```
Before upload:              After upload:
 Files.zip                   Files.zip
    Some_file_with_Å.pdf        Some_file_with_+.pdf  <-- Altered
    Some_file_with_È.pdf        Some_file_with_+.pdf  <-- Altered
    Some_file_with_Ñ.pdf        Some_file_with_-.pdf  <-- Altered (minus?)
    Some_file_with_Ö.pdf        Some_file_with_+.pdf  <-- Altered
```

Case 5: Again the very first archive `È`, `Î`, `Ñ` and `Ö`

```
Before upload:              After upload:
 Files.zip                   Files.zip
    Some_file_with_È.pdf        Some_file_with_+.pdf  <-- Altered
    Some_file_with_Î.pdf        Some_file_with_+.pdf  <-- Altered
    Some_file_with_Ñ.pdf        Some_file_with_-.pdf  <-- Altered (minus?)
    Some_file_with_Ö.pdf        Some_file_with_+.pdf  <-- Altered
```

*Hm.. now everything is altered.*

Case 6: Created a fresh archive with `È`, `Î`, `Ñ` and `Ö`

```
Before upload:              After upload:
 Files.zip                   Files.zip
    Some_file_with_È.pdf        Some_file_with_È.pdf  <-- Not altered
    Some_file_with_Î.pdf        Some_file_with_Î.pdf  <-- Not altered
    Some_file_with_Ñ.pdf        Some_file_with_Ñ.pdf  <-- Not altered
    Some_file_with_Ö.pdf        Some_file_with_Ö.pdf  <-- Not altered
```

---

### **Conclusion: don't edit zipfiles, create a new one every time...**

Apparently php doesn't like modified archives, still weird that it gives a result like that.

Comment: It's recommended to use `move_uploaded_file()` instead of `copy()` and what you have described is not possible unless the integrity of the zip file itself was affected, which you can easily check with `md5sum`.

Comment: @Jack I changed `copy()` to `move_uploaded_file()`. Is it possible to send the MD5 checksum with JavaScript/jQuery and compare it with `md5_file()` in PHP? Also I made the zip myself several times over.

Comment: You can run `md5sum` on the zip file in your machine before you upload it (I'm sure there are tools for both Linux and Windows) and then on the server after you've uploaded it.

Comment: Ok I have compared the checksums of the file before upload on my client, and after upload on the server. Both checksums are `517e5e45a5697c498cfb0e4390adf546`, the same

Comment: So apparently php doesn't like modified archives, still weird that it gives a result like that. Sorry for your troubles and thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Conclusion: don't edit zipfiles, create a new one every time...

Apparently php doesn't like modified archives, still weird that it gives a result like that.

Answer (score 1):

This is a zip encoding problem. On unix server zip decoder thinks that filenames in archive have the same encoding that on server, while Windows uses DOS (OEM) encoding, and Mac OS - UTF-8.

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention that clients run Windows and the server runs Windows Server 2008. So both use DOS encoding, right?

Comment: Not really - since you use PHP, it can include open-source zip library with hardcoded/different encoding. Please also show the code to unzip files.

Comment: The problem isn't in the unzipping, the files are malformed after upload, before unzipping. But I'll add the unzipcode

Comment: If there would be something during upload, zips would be completely unreadable. It is definitely unzip problem. Also I assume that you checked archive on client side - and it is ok there.

Comment: I added the unzip code.
And, as said in the comments on my question: the MD5 checksums are the same, the zip is readable before and after upload. It's just the files inside the zip that have been altered in some way.

Comment: If md5 sums are the same, file IS NOT modified during upload. Filenames of files inside of zip archive are stored in zip file.